# Where can I find a good book to learn Fl Studio?

Tags: theory, self-learning, electronic-music, fl-studio

I'm new to this community, so I hope this is the right place to ask such a question, or else I'm sorry.

I would like to learn how to use Fl studio by myself, just to practice it a little bit in private and have fun. To do so I would like to study it with the help of a good book. I found many tutorials on the internet, but it's always difficult to look for something specific and since I believe that a good book would solve this problem I'm asking you if you know a good one that you can suggest. There are many on the internet, but I don't want to spend money on something that I don't know if it's good or not.

Thank you in advance for any answer!

Alessandro.

Comment: Hi Bman - this question isn't a good fit here, but as you are learning, if you have specific questions about Fl studio, then they can be asked here.

Comment: One way of this could be to start experimenting with the instruments and effects there. When working with an instrument/effect just press F1. FL Studio will open context-sensitive help window for the currently used plugin/effect. Their help is usually very well written and I rarely have issues understanding it.